# Form validation using revealing prototype pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, oop, design-patterns

I feel I should start by saying I'm new the patterning. I'm using the revealing prototype pattern to validate form inputs, etc. This is going to be a validation that is setup as sort of a "template" that will cover 95% of our forms but there will be requirements for certain forms to add additional custom validation down the road.  That being said what I'm wanting to do is create a new form validation object then initialize it.  On initialization all the evaluation magic happens and then will either return a '1' = form is valid or a '0' = form is invalid.  I'm having trouble understanding how I access my 'ok' variable to see if it is a 1 or 0.  Please help and thank you in advance.

---

Here's is the form validation 'class':

```
// Constructor requires the Form's ID of the for you want to validate
// Exmaple:  FormValidator('MyContactForm')
var FormValidator = function(formID) {
    //state
    this.formID = formID;   //I was thinking of having this.formID in case there are two forms that need validating on a single page. (e.g., Search box and Contact Form) I don't seem to be using this correctly?
    this.ok;                //want to access this to see if the form validated or not
    this.currentField;      //using this to identify what form field is getting evaluated
};


FormValidator.prototype = function() {
    //private memebers
    var init = function() {

        // Start looking for input, select or textarea that has the 'required' attribute    
        $('input[required], select[required], textarea[required]').each(function() {

            //--Set Current Field Under Evaluation--//
            this.currentField = $(this).attr('id');

            validateRequiredFields.call(this);

            if(!this.ok) {
                return false;
            };

        });
    },
    validateRequiredFields = function() {
        // Check Dropdown/Text inputs for validity //
        if($(this.currentField).selectedIndex == 0 || $.trim($(this.currentField).val()) == '') {
            this.ok = 0;
            return false;
        }
        // Check Radio/Checkbox inputs for validity //
        else if(this.currentField.attr('type') == 'radio' || this.currentField.attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
            var optChecked = $('input[name="' + this.currentField.attr('name') + '"]:checked')
            if($(optChecked).length == 0) {
                this.ok = 0;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            this.ok = 1;
        }
    }


    return {
        //public members
        init: init
    };

}();
```

Create new object and initialize it:

```
var validateForm = new FormValidator('mobileSchedulingForm');
validateForm.init();

console.log(validateForm.ok); //undefined (how come?)

if(validateForm.ok) {  //Eval failing cause 'validateForm.ok' is undefined?
  // do something now that the form is valid
}
```

---

So, what am I missing / misunderstanding?

Comment: Edited my answer, there are multiple errors in the code you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set the .ok value to anything in the constructor so I think your jquery for each is empty:

```
var FormValidator = function(formID) {
    this.formID = formID;
    this.ok=1;// set default to 1 (empty jquery select will pass)
    this.currentField;
};
```

And in init try this:

```
   console.log("Checking inputs:",
       $('input[required], select[required], textarea[required]').length);
```

In your init funciton before doing the .each loop

In your ini you call `validateRequiredFields.call(this);` but you call it within a `$(selector).each` loop so at that moment the `this` value is that of the input and then later you set the .ok property of input to 0 or 1. This can be solved with:

```
var init = function() {
    var me=this;
    // Start looking for input, select or textarea that has the 'required' attribute    
    $('input[required], select[required], textarea[required]').each(function() {
        // this is the text input here
        me.currentField = $(this);
        validateRequiredFields.call(me);
        if(!me.ok) {
            return false;
        };

    });
    return true;
},
```

Then you set the `this.currentField` to the id of the input, maybe it's better to just set it to the jQuery object (see code above) and using the new this.currentField below.

```
validateRequiredFields = function() {
    // Check Dropdown/Text inputs for validity //
    if(this.currentField.selectedIndex == 0 || $.trim(this.currentField.val()) == '') {
    console.log("setting this.ok to 0",this);
        this.ok = 0;
        return false;
    }
    // Check Radio/Checkbox inputs for validity //
    else if(this.currentField.attr('type') == 'radio' || this.currentField.attr('type') == 'checkbox') {
        var optChecked = $('input[name="' + this.currentField.attr('name') + '"]:checked')
        if($(optChecked).length == 0) {
            this.ok = 0;
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
    console.log("setting this.ok");
        this.ok = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked!  Thank you.  I figured that I wasn't working with `this` correctly.  That's the noob part.  Also, thanks for the heads up on assigning `ok` a value in the constructor.  Should all states in the constructor have a value no matter what?  So would it be better to set `this.currentField` to an empty string or is just creating it fine? Thanks again for the help.  I have more of the validation to build out but I wanted to get the simple foundation working first.  Hopefully this will carry me all the way. :)

Comment: @WizzyBoom ` Should all states in the constructor have a value no matter what?` No, that's not needed. The ok should be set to 1 because if there are no elements to check (no required fields) the form will allways be unvalid because ok will be undefined.